# REGEXP_LIKE conversion in SQL Server T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, design-patterns, patindex

I have come across this line in an old report that needs converting to SQL Server.

```
REGEXP_LIKE (examCodes, learner_code)
```

examCodes being the source and learner_code being the pattern. I know that SQL Server doesn't have REGEXP_LIKE and most places tell you to use PATINDEX.

Here's me thinking that this would work:

```
PATINDEX(learner_code, examCodes)
```

But I get the error:

```
Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 54
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'WHERE'.
```

On MSDN the syntax is specified as,

```
PATINDEX ('%pattern%',expression)
```

But learner_code is a field and I can't specify a pattern?

I did not write this report in the first place so I'm puzzled to what the pattern it's looking for anyway.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WHERE PATINDEX ('%pattern%',expression)  !=0
```

If pattern is found , PATINDEX returns non zero value and you need to do a comparison in WHERE clause.
A `WHERE` clause must be followed by comparison operation that returns true / false.
May be you are using PATINDEX without doing the comparison and that is why  error message shows non boolean expression near WHERE clause.

To search for pattern **learner_code** with wildcard character

```
WHERE PATINDEX ('%' + CAST(learner_code AS VARCHAR) +'%',examCodes)  !=0
```

Answer (score 2):

ORACLE'S REGEXP_LIKE supports actual regular expressions, PATINDEX only supports the % and _ wildcards, the [] list/range, and the ^ list/range negation.